# How do I get the volume size of an EKS NodeGroup using eksctl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I would like full details on NodeGroups in an EKS cluster, for example volume size  as set using `--node-volume-size` in the command `eksctl create nodegroup ...` but also many other details of a NodeGroup that can be set with that command.

`eksctl get nodegroup` gives limited data, omitting volume size.  See below.

`kubectl get node` (or `kubectl describe node`) gives more information (see at bottom). However, this is information for the Node, not the Node Group. Node Groups have their own details, such as configuration for auto-scaling, and in fact can be zero-sized. Also, the `kubectl` output does not  match the `--node-volume-size` value -- in this case 33 GB, as can be confirmed in the AWS EBS console.

I need data on the level of `eksctl` (EC2 VMs) rather than `kubectl` (Kubernetes nodes), though of course these do align.

This is just one example of the fields set in  `eksctl create nodegroup ...` which are not in the (rather thin-looking) JSON.  How can I get a full description of the Node Group?

```
$ eksctl get nodegroup --name  one-node-group  --cluster clus-bumping  --region=us-east-2 --output json

[
    {
        "StackName": "eksctl-cluster1-nodegroup-one-node-group",
        "Cluster": "cluster1",
        "Name": "one-node-group",
        "MaxSize": 1,
        "MinSize": 1,
        "DesiredCapacity": 1,
        "InstanceType": "t2.small",
        "ImageID": "",
        "CreationTime": "2020-05-27T07:18:32.496Z",
        "NodeInstanceRoleARN": ""
    }
]
```

Relevant output of `kubectl` concerning volumes:

```
% kubectl describe node 
Name:               ip-192-168-39-36.us-east-2.compute.internal ...
Capacity: ...
 attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39 ...
ephemeral-storage:           34590700Ki ...
Allocatable:
 attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39
 ephemeral-storage:           30805047244 ...
 Resource                    Requests    Limits ...
  --------                    --------    ------
 ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)      0 (0%) ...
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0           0   ...
```

Comment: What volume size do you mean?

Comment: The thing you configure with   --node-volume-size in the command `eksctl create cluster ...`  or `eksctl create nodegroup...`  It is the base disk attached for the OS to boot.

Comment: `kubectl get nodes -o yaml`, did you get what you need?

Comment: @BMW I edited the question. kubectl get node gives volume information (see at bottom). However, it is not clear which of these metrics exactly matches the --node-volume-size value -- I need data on the level of eksctl (EC2 VMs) rather than kubectl (Kubernetes nodes), though of course these do align.

Comment: @BMW Also, a node group has different info than a node, for example autoscaling config. In fact, there could be a node group with zero nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: This is simply a limitation in `eksctl`. The limitation exists because the node-group configuration is not  implicit  in the EC2-based cluster itself, but rather it would need to be saved specially in cluster metadata.

See eksctl GitHub issues:  [2255](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/2255)  and [642](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/642).

Yet the information *does* exist, and you can get it with the AWS SDK for EKS function [`DescribeNodegroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v2/api/service/eks/#Client.DescribeNodegroupRequest).